# LAS dataset to raster: 'no spatial reference exists'?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, lidar, lasd

I am trying to make a DEM from my LAS dataset and I am using `LAS Dataset to Raster` tool in Conversion Tools. But I am getting the following error:

> No Spatial Reference exists.
>
> The table was not found.[VAT_Suwannee_Las4]
>
> ERROR 999999

The complete syntax submitted to the geoprocessing framework was:

```
arcpy.LasDatasetToRaster_conversion(in_las_dataset="C:/Users‌​/Arsalan/Documents/A‌​rcGIS/Suwannee.lasd"‌​, out_raster="C:/Users/Arsalan/Documents/ArcGIS/Default.gdb/Su‌​wannee_Las3", value_field="ELEVATION", interpolation_type="BINNING AVERAGE LINEAR", data_type="INT", sampling_type="CELLSIZE", sampling_value="1", z_factor="1")
```

This is the screenshot showing the error:

[image]

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Please include text rather than a picture that shows us your precise tool parameters and error message.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: That's the error message but what were the parameter values that you used with the tool when you saw the error?

Comment: interpolation type is Binning, Average, Linear.
Output Datatype is INT, but I also tried FLOAT and I get the same error.
Sampling Type, CELLSIZE.
Sampling value is 1, Z Factor is 1.

Comment: What was the precise and complete syntax that you submitted to the tool?

Comment: I do not have the syntax code, I used the toolbox

Comment: You should be able to right-click in the Results window to get what the tool submitted to the geoprocessing framework.

Comment: oops I found it. this is the syntax:  
arcpy.LasDatasetToRaster_conversion(in_las_dataset="C:/Users/Arsalan/Documents/ArcGIS/Suwannee.lasd", out_raster="C:/Users/Arsalan/Documents/ArcGIS/Default.gdb/Suwannee_Las3", value_field="ELEVATION", interpolation_type="BINNING AVERAGE LINEAR", data_type="INT", sampling_type="CELLSIZE", sampling_value="1", z_factor="1")

Comment: Please [edit] that into your question.

Comment: What geographic and projected coordinate system is your data in? I'm having the same problem with one of my projections.  I get this error for my unprojected LASD, not the ones that have a projected coordinate system.

Comment: I think my LASD was not projected and I was not able to project it. So I found another LiDAR data from the region. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

> I think my LASD was not projected and I was not able to project it. ...

As per [OP's comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238485/las-dataset-to-raster-no-spatial-reference-exists/245296#comment376374_238485), the error: `no spatial reference exists` was probably caused by a missing spatial reference in the LAS dataset layer.

Either the .las files which the LAS dataset was referencing did not originally have CRS, or if they did, it was not defined when creating the LAS dataset.

Another possible cause for such type of error would be the .las files having the CRS defined in Geographic Coordinates, in which case some tools will not to work. See the [ArcGIS help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/LAS_dataset_considerations/015w00000069000000/ESRI_SECTION1_104F85DA2EBC405E9EEBBFF61208759E/):

> It is recommended that LAS data be delivered and consumed in a projected coordinate system, for example, UTM or NAD83 State Plane. LAS data that is captured in Geographic coordinates can be displayed, but some functionality may fail or be suboptimal.

The above quote was also discussed in [When to reproject LAS data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102636/when-to-reproject-las-data)

For defining or reprojecting a CRS in a LAS dataset refer to:

- [Converting a .lasd (Lidar) coordinate system?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72356/converting-a-lasd-lidar-coordinate-system/72390#72390)